# userManager.GetRolesAsync() returns list of roles but userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync() returns empty list

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.2, usermanager

**Problem**

The below code fetches the roles of users but not the users in that particular role. Is there something missing?

**Code**

```
    public void SeedRolesData(PartnerDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any())
        {
            context.Roles.AddRange(this.Roles);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void SeedUserRoles(PartnerDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.UserRoles.Any())
        {
            context.UserRoles.AddRange(this.UserRolesMapping);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public List<IdentityRole> Roles => new List<IdentityRole>
    {
        new IdentityRole { Id="1", Name = ApplicationDefaultRoles.admin }
    };

    public List<IdentityUserRole<string>> UserRolesMapping => new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>
    {
        new IdentityUserRole<string> { UserId = "1", RoleId = "1" }
    };
```

Getting Roles by user and Users By Roles

```
   var roles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(new User() {
    Id = "1",
    UserTypeId = (int)UserTypeEnum.admin,
    FirstName = "Sam",
    LastName = "Ram"
   }).Result; --> Returns result

   var user= userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(ApplicationDefaultRoles.admin).Result; --> Returns empty list.
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data for the Roles should also include the NormalizedName to fetch the users in role. Below is the updated sample roles data.

```
    public List<IdentityRole> Roles => new List<IdentityRole>
    {
        new IdentityRole {
        Id="1", 
        Name = ApplicationDefaultRoles.admin, 
        NormalizedName = ApplicationDefaultRoles.admin.ToUpperInvariant() }
    };
```